# Error with validation DigitalPersona SDK Excepción from HRESULT: 0xFFFFFFE3 (SDK Error = -29)

Tags: vb.net, fingerprint, biometrics

I am verifying the trace I receive from a SQL Server DB, the Data type is varbinary (MAX) but I receive this exception and I have no idea what it may be, I leave you the code of the query where I bring the data and the method it processes

> Exception:
>
> > Exception From HRESULT: 0xFFFFFFE3

Log from the exception (This be in spanish):

```
Consulte el final de este mensaje para obtener más detalles sobre cómo invocar a la depuración 
Just-In-Time (JIT) en lugar de a este cuadro de diálogo.

************** Texto de la excepción **************
DPFP.Error.SDKException: Event Handler has generated an Exception ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Excepción de HRESULT: 0xFFFFFFE3
   en DPFP.Verification.Verification.MC_verifyFeaturesEx(SafeHandle mcContext, Int32 templateSize, Byte[] templatePt, Int32 featureSetSize, Byte[] featureSet, Int32 reserved0, IntPtr reserved1, IntPtr reserved2, IntPtr reserved3, Double& achievedFar)
   en DPFP.Verification.Verification.Verify(FeatureSet FeatureSet, Template Template, Int32 FARRequested)
   en DPFP.Verification.Verification.Verify(FeatureSet FeatureSet, Template Template, Result& Result)
   en VerifyEnrollerApp.VerifyFinger.Process(Sample Sample) en c:\users\desarrollo 02\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\VerifyEnrollerApp\VerifyEnrollerApp\Form1.vb:línea 322
   en VerifyEnrollerApp.VerifyFinger.OnComplete(Object Capture, String ReaderSerialNumber, Sample Sample) en c:\users\desarrollo 02\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\VerifyEnrollerApp\VerifyEnrollerApp\Form1.vb:línea 246
   en DPFP.Capture.Capture.MessageReceived(Message& m)
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
   en DPFP.Capture.Capture.MessageReceived(Message& m)
   en DPFP.Capture.Capture.MessageEvents.MessageWindow.WndProc(Message& m)


************** Ensamblados cargados **************
mscorlib
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 4.6.1087.0 built by: NETFXREL4STAGE
    Código base: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities
    Versión del ensamblado: 11.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 11.0.50727.1
    Código base: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities/11.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 4.6.1087.0 built by: NETFXREL4STAGE
    Código base: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
```

> Select to the DataBase

```
Private Template As DPFP.Template
Public Function CargarHuella()
        Dim conexion As New SqlConnection(Cadena_Conexion)
        Dim a As Byte()
        Dim Result As String = ""
        Dim sql As String
        Try

            conexion.Open()
            sql = "SELECT H_1 FROM HUELLAS WHERE H_Nit_ID = '11' AND H_TypeDocument_ID = '1' AND H_Document_ID = '1032494911'"

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conexion)

        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        If reader.Read Then
            a = reader.GetValue(0)
        End If
            reader.Close()
            cmd.Dispose()
            conexion.Dispose()

            Dim str As New MemoryStream
            str = New MemoryStream(a) 'Convertirmos los bites en Memory

            Dim template As New DPFP.Template(str) 'Volvemos el Memory en Template para verificar

            CargarTemplate(template)

            Result = "Exito"
        Catch ex As Exception
            Result = "Error: " & ex.ToString
        End Try

        Return Result
    End Function

Protected Sub CargarTemplate(ByVal template As DPFP.Template)
        If Me.TXTMensajes.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim d As New AddTemplateCallBack(AddressOf CargarTemplate)
            Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {template})
        Else
            Me.Template = template
        End If
    End Sub
```

> Verification Process

```
Private Verificator As DPFP.Verification.Verification     
Protected Sub ProcessSample(ByVal Sample As DPFP.Sample)
            DibujarMapa(Sample)

            Dim caracteristicas As DPFP.FeatureSet = ExtraerCaracteristicas(Sample, DPFP.Processing.DataPurpose.Enrollment)

            If (Not caracteristicas Is Nothing) Then
                ' Comparamos las caracteristicas de la huella tomada con las del template que tenemos
                Dim result As DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result = New DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result()
                Verificator.Verify(caracteristicas, Template, result) '<----HERE IS WHERE THE EXCEPTION IS SHOW
                If result.Verified Then
                    SendMensaje("Ok", "Ok", 3)
                Else
                    SendMensaje("KO", "KO", 1)
                End If
            End If
        End Sub
```

What may be failing, or what am I failing?

*PD: Sorry for my bad english :(*

Answer (score 0):

> SOLUTION

Ok I solved it in the following way, I'll explain it first.

Apparently I had to instantiate as a new object the features that are extracted, I crawled with a try-catch to get the error code issued by the SDK on the failed process, the error is the -29 and in the documentation explain that it is when there is a Error in the features and can not be converted correctly I leave the code with the correction, it works perfectly for me.

```
''' <summary>
''' Todo el proceso que se encarga de validar la captura de la huella
''' </summary>
''' <param name="Sample"></param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Protected Sub ProcessSample(ByVal Sample As DPFP.Sample)
    Try
        DibujarMapa(Sample)

        Dim caracteristicas As DPFP.FeatureSet = New DPFP.FeatureSet '<---- I added this line and ready, it was fixed
        caracteristicas = ExtraerCaracteristicas(Sample, DPFP.Processing.DataPurpose.Verification)

        If (Not caracteristicas Is Nothing) Then
            ' Comparamos las caracteristicas de la huella tomada con las del template que tenemos
            Dim result As DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result = New DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result()
            CodesErrors.GetTypeCode()
            Verificator.Verify(caracteristicas, Template, result)
            If result.Verified Then
                Huella = True
                UpdateCalidad("Mensaje: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Huella verificada")
                SendMensaje("Ok", "Ok...", 3)
            Else
                Huella = False
                UpdateCalidad("Mensaje: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Huella no coincide")
                SendMensaje("KO", "KO...", 1)
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        If ex.HResult = -29 Then '<-- This is the error code from de SDK exception
            SendMensaje("Lo sentimos, ocurrió un error durante la validación de la huella." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "• Message: 'Invalid Feature Set Type'" & vbCrLf & "• Exception Code: " & ex.HResult, "Disculpenos :( - Error Número (" & ex.HResult & ")", 1)
        Else
            SendMensaje("• Exception Message: " & ex.Message & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "• Exception Code: " & ex.HResult, "Error al Verificar", 1)
        End If
    End Try

End Sub
```